# Can't use constants in Cuda

Tags: c++, cuda

Example:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

__constant__ int32_t m;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    void* s;
    int r = cudaGetSymbolAddress( &s, m);
    assert( r == cudaSuccess );
    return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
$ nvcc test.cu -o test -arch compute_20 -code sm_20
```

Run:

```
$ ./test
```

Get:

```
test: test.cu:15: int main(int, char**): Assertion `r == cudaSuccess' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

(If that makes any difference, I tested this in two different cards in two different computers. Cuda  6 in both cases.)

What's wrong there?

Comment: OK, I'll bite. What's the error you're actually getting, i.e. what's the value of `r`? And shouldn't the argument be `&m`?

Comment: @Angew It should work both ways.... nonetheless, I tried your suggestion. It doesn't work either. The error is cudaErrorInvalidSymbol

Comment: Which GPUs did you test on? I get the same error if the code is compiled for target architecture higher than the GPU on which the code is executed.

Comment: @sgar91 I tested this on a GTX 770 and on a GTX 560ti... Hmm, I checked that, on the GTX 770 it can be solved moving the flags all the way up to 30.... can you elaborate your comments on an answer? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact reason as both of the mentioned GPUs are higher than CC 2.0. Error comes if **Target > GPU**. In your case, it is reverse.

Comment: @sgar91 Well, I have had a couple of days with Cuda 6 and this is not the first very strange thing that I encounter... my opinion: a bug-fix release can't come too soon...

Comment: If you find bugs you should file them at https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cuda-registered-developer-program (you may need to log in first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sgar91 pointed out, the problem is the compilation target mismatching the actual GPU.

To be specific: you have `-code sm_20` in your options which will make the compiler build a binary for sm_20 and there will be no PTX in your binary - that means it cannot be JIT compiled for your devices (compute capability > 2.0) and hence your GPU operations will fail. You should have `-code compute_20` or one or more `-gencode` arguments (see [nvcc manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html) for more examples).

Some examples:

```
$ nvcc test.cu -o test -arch compute_20 -code compute_20
$ nvcc test.cu -o test -gencode="arch=compute_20,code=\"compute_20,sm_20,sm_30\""
$ nvcc test.cu -o test -gencode="arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,sm_21\"" -gencode="arch=compute_30,code=\"compute_30,sm_30\""
```

Rather than doing an assert on your CUDA API call, you should report the actual error since that would have been helpful here.

Comment: Thanks for the help Tom! This looks indeed very interesting! BTW, you work for an awesome company.